# How can an object access its owner's global?

Tags: python

If we have something like:

**foo.py**

```
from bar import bar

class foo:
    global black;
    black = True;

    bar = bar()

    bar.speak()

f = foo()
```

**bar.py**

```
class bar:
    def speak():
    if black:
        print "blaaack!"
    else:
        print "whitttte!"
```

when we run
`python foo.py`

we get

`NameError: global name 'black' is not defined`

What's the best practise for doing something like this?

Should I pass it in the method?

Have the bar class have a parent variable?

For context, in practise the `black` global is for a debugging step.

Comment: You need to define black before you global it (if I'm not horribly mistaken)

Comment: @jamylak Can you perhaps suggest how one would pass around this kind of flag witghout using globals?

Comment: Wait i assumed you had defined it. @Elias is correct

Comment: @dwjohnston, if you want it to be shared across all instances, just refer to it as `Foo.black` (assuming you made your class named `Foo` rather than `foo`, in accordance with PEP-8). That said, your example doesn't make it clear why you want this to be global rather than class- or instance-scoped.

Comment: why are you doing this in a class body...?  is this something you want to turn on temporarily sometimes, or for an entire run of your program, or what?  why do you need to get the "owner's" global specifically, instead of just importing foo?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, globals are specific to a module. So the global in your foo.py is not accessible in your bar.py--not the way you have it written at least.

If you want every instance of foo to have its own value of `black`, then use an instance variable as Ivelin has shown. If you want every instance of foo to share the same value of `black` use a class variable.

---

Using an instance variable:

```
# foo.py
from bar import bar

class foo:
    # Python "constructor"..
    def __init__(self):
        # Define the instance variables
        self.bar = bar()
        # Make bar talk
        self.bar.speak()

    # Create a function for making this foo's bar speak whenever we want
    def bar_speak(self):
        self.bar.speak()

################################################################################
# bar.py
class bar:
    # Python "constructor"..
    def __init__(self):
         # Define the instance variables
        self.black = True
    def speak(self):
        if self.black:
            print "blaaack!"
        else:
            print "whitttte!"
```

Playing with the code:

```
>>> f = foo()
blaaack!
>>> b = foo()
blaaack!
>>> b.bar.black = False
>>> b.bar_speak()
whitttte!
>>> f.bar_speak()
blaaack!
```

---

Using a class variable:

```
# foo.py
from bar import bar

class foo:
    # Python "constructor"..
    def __init__(self):
        # Define the instance variables
        self.bar = bar()
        # Make bar talk
        self.bar.speak()

    # Create a function for making this foo's bar speak whenever we want
    def bar_speak(self):
        self.bar.speak()

################################################################################
# bar.py
class bar:
    black = True
    def speak():
        if bar.black:
            print "blaaack!"
        else:
            print "whitttte!"
```

Playing with the code:

```
>>> f = foo()
blaaack!
>>> b = foo()
blaaack!
>>> bar.black = False
>>> b.bar_speak()
whitttte!
>>> f.bar_speak()
whitttte!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

foo.py

```
from bar import bar

class foo:
    bar = bar(black=True)
    bar.speak()

f = foo()
```

bar.py

```
class bar:
    def __init__(black):
        self.black = black
    def speak():
        if self.black:
            print "blaaack!"
        else:
            print "whitttte!”
```

Comment: Does this actually answer the question? I don't see it demonstrating anything functionally equivalent to globals (such as class-scoped variables). One can hope that if the OP asked for a global, they had a reason -- such as wanting to be able to throw the switch in a way that would impact all instances, including previously-created ones. At a minimum, the distinction between the behavior of the requested solution and the behavior of the suggested solution should be made clear.

Comment: The context given (a debug toggle) makes it clear that instance variables are genuinely not global enough; it should be possible to turn debugging on and off without modifying every previously-created object.